# Could not parse the remainder: '[1]' from 'form2[1]'

Tags: python, django

This is my index2.html

I'm trying to display the area where I could input the second element's data of form2. form2 consists of fields from the database.

```
<h1>Fill the form below</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>Enter second area</h1>
        {{  form2[1] }}<br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit file1"/>
    </form>
```

Displaying the inputting fields for all the fields in the form2(refer below) is working good.

```
<h1>Fill the form below</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form2 %}
        {{field}}<br><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit file1"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The Django template language allows index access via `{{ form2.1 }}`.

Comment: What is your question? Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks. That helped in removing the error. But the fields to enter input are not being displayed on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access django form's fields by index, you must use key. So you need to do something like this:

```
{{ form2.myField }}
{{ form2.myField2 }}
```

Trying to access form fields by index will not work:

```
{{ form2[1] }} // Incorrect syntax
{{ form2.1 }}  // correct syntax but you can access fields using index, must use key.
```

Answer (score 0):

> form2 consists of fields from the database

From the code you're posting, it really looks like `form2` doesn't "consists for fields from the database" but is a Django `Form` (eventually a `ModelForm` but that's irrelevant here). Forms are iterable indeed, but in Python lots of things are iterable that are not list or do not support indexed access - dicts are a very obvious example, and so are forms: iterating over a form iterates on the form's bound fields.

If you want to access a specific field from a form, you have to name it, so assuming your form's field is named "area2" (well you didn't post a proper MCVE so we have to assume a lot), this would be `form2.area2`.